# CSS Float Images, Remove margin each line

Tags: css, css-float, margin

Im trying to align multiple Images or DIVs.
i get the content from wordpress.

```
#wrapper{    
width:800px;
}

.image{
width:125px;
height:100px;
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
}
```

This causes the last image to go to the next line.

i found

```
#wrapper div:first-child{
    margin-left:0px;
    }
```

helps me with the first line but the next lines are "broken" again.
how can i align 6 images in a row with ^n Pictures?

Answer (score 3):

That's indeed a common design problem. I used to fix it by adding 10px to the container, but nowadays I always use a jQuery fix:

```
$("#wrapper .image:nth-child(6n+1)").find('img').css('margin-left','0');
```

See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JZfJG/1/)

Or you could do it CSS only, but this will only work in real browsers (not in <=IE8)

```
.image:nth-child(6n+1) {
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JZfJG/4/)

Comment: i thought of that solution but was hoping to do that only by css..
but this would work. thank you

Comment: haha, wow. thats nice but maybe ill will use the jquery solution. seems to be secure. But yout jfiddle gave me an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/sCYuj/30/

Comment: that's a nice one too - 'm feeling a bit stupid i never came up with that myself...

Comment: ;-) it took me now one day to find that... and it was luck.
but it isnt perfect too. when i add one more picture it has faulty margins argh ! maybe the jquery is still the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the total width of the images, padding and margin are too wide for your container width. Try increasing the container width to confirm this.